# Spatial statistics within a polygon in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, spatial-statistics, google

I am wondering if the information provided in this exchange is still accurate.

[number of pixels inside a polygon in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255719/number-of-pixels-inside-a-polygon-in-google-earth-engine/256221#256221?newreg=9ee4543cf86640b6b8f9c48f173b0120)

I am trying to calculate mean precipitation within a river basin, where precipitation data are in a raster and the basins are a polygon. Using Google Earth Engine, I have already calculated average areal weighted precipitation, but I am having trouble discovering the exact formula/calculation process GEE uses to calculate an areal weighted mean.

According to the [GEE Changelog on 2017-08-28](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/changelog), there appears to be no minimal coverage required for a pixel to be added to a weighted calculation. Is this correct? So, even if 0.01% of a precipitation pixel is contained within a basin, then it should be included in the calculation of a weighted mean?

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region#pixels-in-the-region):

For weighted reducers: pixels are included if at least (approximately) 0.5% of the pixel is in the region and the image's mask is non-zero; their weight is the minimum of the image's mask and the (approximate) fraction of the pixel covered by the region.  So approximately 0.005 of the pixel area must be in the region, but if the image mask is zero, the corresponding weight is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with you. I tried your code, and found that if we change the shape of polygon 2 in https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fuoedwq%2Flearn%3Areducer%20test_scale%20count, we'll get different results. Therefore, I think the results are definitely calculated average areal weighted.

Comment: Please include your code in the body of the answer in addition to the url. That way, if the url ever goes 404, your answer remains valid.